# Adding in a hit counter to Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm creating a custom component for Joomla 2.5. I want to add in a hit counter for the detailed view (like on Joomla content etc.)

So I've done some research and found the `JTable::hit` function which I'm assuming is what I need (Joomla docs page [here](http://docs.joomla.org/JTable%3a%3ahit/11.1)). However I'm highly unclear as to where I need to implement this. Is it in the model somewhere when I retrieve the row from the database - or is it somewhere in the view? Advise would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at how they did it in Joomla, you will see that they implemented the functionality in the model, and call the method from the view.

For example, `article.php` model has

```
public function hit($pk = 0)
{
        $hitcount = JRequest::getInt('hitcount', 1);

        if ($hitcount)
        {
            // Initialise variables.
            $pk = (!empty($pk)) ? $pk : (int) $this->getState('article.id');
            $db = $this->getDbo();

            $db->setQuery(
                    'UPDATE #__content' .
                    ' SET hits = hits + 1' .
                    ' WHERE id = '.(int) $pk
            );

            if (!$db->query()) {
                    $this->setError($db->getErrorMsg());
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
}
```

and

`view.html.php` has

```
$model = $this->getModel();
$model->hit();
```

Comment: Beautiful. I actually used the code in the weblinks component as it uses that `JTable::hit` which means the model function is only 4 lines long actually. But this got me set on the right track at last. God knows how I missed this function on my first hunt around the Joomla models/components etc. Thankyou :)

Comment: beware of the cache though: you risk getting just one hit per cache refresh, not one hit per visit.  To get one hit per visit, you would need to invoke a counter from javascript on the client, or work around the cache for your module by inserting the hit() before the getData() /getList() in the module main function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Table Class. Work in Joomla 3 and Joomla 4.

**Your model**

```
use Joomla\CMS\Table\Table;

public function hit($id = 0)
{
    Table::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_mycomp_name/tables');
    $table = Table::getInstance('my_table_name', 'Table', array());
    $table->hit($id);
    return true;
}
```

**Your *view.html.php***

```
$model = $this->getModel('model_name');
$model->hit($id);
```

You can use this to increment any column. To do this, you need to override the column.

```
$table->setColumnAlias('hits', 'new_column_name');
$table->hit($id);
```