# Article hit counter and Joomla 2.5.x cache?

Tags: caching, joomla2.5, counter-cache, hit, hitcounter

There was a comment on [Adding in a hit counter to Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165840/adding-in-a-hit-counter-to-joomla) that the cache impacts the stock hit counter. Do you have any idea how I can fix that bug in Joomla or where I can start to look in the code?

I see it's submitted in the bug tracker but nobody is assigned to it. I believe the hits must be increased before the cache is served, and at the moment the function that generates the content is actually the one that calls the hit increasing function, so that's why the hits only increase upon a fresh article render.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla counts and update the article hits when the page is built, but if the caching plugin is enabled and the page has been cached to disk, the page is loaded directly from the cache directory, without updating the number of views. You can try this joomla hack here:
[Joomla Hit Counter Updater](http://scoptop.com/software-products/joomla/5-joomla-hit-counter-updater)
Even though it's not free, it might help you.

Comment: Thanks.  I see it's only for 1.5 but that's the only answer I got so far